# How to get list of folders from Schedule.Service in powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script that lists the tasks in the root folder of task scheduler.

I can hard code sub folders, but I would like to be able to query the sub folders so it will work when new folders are added.  Can this be done and, if so, how?

The relevant bit of script showing hard coded sub folder "Reports" being accessed:

```
$sch = New-Object -ComObject("Schedule.Service")
...
$tasks = $sch.GetFolder("\Reports").GetTasks(0)
$tasks | ForEach-Object{
...
```

Comment: If you're on Windows 8.1 or Server 2012 R2, Powershell includes [a Task Scheduler module](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj649816(v=wps.630).aspx).

Comment: Otherwise, you might try [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2009/04/01/how-can-i-best-work-with-task-scheduler.aspx), but I'm not sure it's doing what you want.  You can also try digging through the Schedule.Service API [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383607(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind - figured it out:

```
$root = $sch.GetFolder("\")
$subfolders = $root.GetFolders(0)
$subfolders | foreach-object{
  $tasks = $_.GetTasks(0)
  ...
```